# How can I generate a console-less program in ocaml?

Tags: console, window, ocaml

I'm trying to make a Ocaml graphics program in Windows, but I cannot generate it without the console window.

The correct command should be:
ocamlopt -o test.exe -ccopt "-subsystem console" graphics.cmxa test.ml

However I receive the following error :

ld: cannot find -lcomdlg32
** Fatal error: Error during linking

Im' working on windows 10, 64 bits, having installed 32 bit ocaml
ocpwin32-20160113-4.02.1+ocp1-mingw32

(Just to be able to use also ocaml-top, that comes only in 32 bit version).

Any suggestion ?

Comment: How did you install OCaml? ([This](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocpwin-distrib)?) Also, can you give us the content of `test.ml`?